# Irreductible polynomial on a finite field of degree as large as wanted

Tags: finite-fields

Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a finite field, is it true that for any $n\ge 0$ there exists an irreductible polynomial $ P \in \mathbb{F}[X]$ of degree larger than $n$ ?

Comment: For each finite field $\Bbb F$ and each number $n\geq 1$ there is an irreducible polynomial of degree $n$.

Comment: Hint: a finite field cannot be algebraically closed

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Yes, thank you.